# scrollTo not works at ALL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, visualforce, scrollto

I am a salesforce developer i wanto scroll up and down on swipe up and down its easy i done with it , it work perfectly on all browser and all device browser like (iPhone/Pad/Andy) but in browser , we have one app called saleforce1 when i open the same page in saleforce1 "scrollTo" not work at all i try below trick but unfortunately not of them is working, help needed.

i try :

```
window.scrollTo(10,10);

$('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:1000},'slow'); 

$('html').stop().animate({scrollTop:1000},'slow'); 

setTimeout(function(){ 
  window.scrollTo(10,10);
}, 3000);
```

PS : why window.scrollTo not working sp in App on iOS and Android it works fine on both os browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scroll `window` because it's not a DOM element it's an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). If you want to scroll the whole page, do something like this:

```
$('body').scrollTo(10, 10);
```

Hope, that works.

Comment: first thanks for the immediate reply , but this wont work for me unfortunately , i dont know why the hell this is not working in app , its work perfectly on mobile or ipad browser(all).but appreciate your answer.

Comment: setTimeout( function() {
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'hidden');
    $('body').scrollTop(0);
    $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto'); 
 }, 500 ); This work for me on android but yet IPad not working